# Suppose $X$ has an unconditional basis. Can it be indecomposable?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

If $X$ is a Banach, then $X$ is indecomposable if $X = M \oplus N$ implies that $M$ or $N$ is finite dimensional.

An unconditional basis is a set $\{e_n\}$ such that every $x$ can be written uniquely as 
$$x = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_ne_n$$ 
$(a_n = a_n(x))$ and the convergence is unconditional, i.e. it converges for every permutation (note this is implied by, but does not imply absolute convergence.)

As a consequence of the uniform boundedness theorem, the partial sum projections $s_n(x):= a_1 + ... + a_n$ are continuous.

Unconditional convergence of a sum $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x_n$ is equivalent to convergence of the sum along every increasing subsequence of integers.

Let $\mathbb{N} = \{n_k\} \sqcup \{n_j\}$. Does it follow that 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_ne_n \mapsto \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_{n_j}e_{n_j}$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_ne_n \mapsto \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{n_k}e_{n_k}$$

define bounded projections? I.e. are the spaces $\overline{span(e_{n_j})}$ and $\overline{span(e_{n_k})}$ complemented? I think this is why the resolution of the unconditional basic sequence problem implies the existence of a hereditarily indecomposable space (every closed subspace of $X$ is indecomposable), but I cannot tell if I'm missing something.

Comment: The mapping you define are bounded projections. See, e.g., page 18 in *Classical Banach Spaces I*, Lindenstrauss and Tzafriri. (For an unconditional  basic sequence $(x_i)$, the convergence of $\sum_i\alpha_i x_i$ implies the convergence of $\sum_j \alpha_{i_j} x_{i_j}$; use the Closed Graph Theorem.)

Comment: @DavidMitra Thank you. If you post as an answer I will accept (for future reference for others)

Comment: @DavidMitra Is there any way to tell when the two subspaces described above are isomorphic (linearly homeomorphic)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned by David Mitra, these are bounded projections.

However, ranges of such projections are usually non-isomorphic. You can already find a counterexample in $\ell_1\oplus \ell_2$, but the most striking example is Tsirelson's space for which we have continuum many isomorphic types; this is Corollary VII.b.3 in

> P. G. Casazza and T. J. Shura, Tsirelson’s space. Lecture Notes in Mathematics 1363. Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 1989.

Comment: Thanks for the reference!